# select top one row each based on foreign key

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to list the only top latest one row from each   foreign key column.

Eg.
I have a below child table:

```
mysql> select tstatus_id,trip_id,trip_title,trip_id from trip_history_status;
+------------+---------+-------------+ 
| tstatus_id | trip_id | trip_title  | 
+------------+---------+-------------+ 
|         33 |      35 | Jitesh Trip |  
|         34 |      36 | Test_trip   | 
|         35 |      36 | Test_trip1  | 
|         36 |      36 | Test_trip2  |
|         37 |      36 | Test_trip3  | 
+------------+---------+-------------+
```

where,

- `tstatus_id` = primary key(autoincreement) of table `trip_history_status`
- `trip_id`   = foreign key from a parent table `tripdetails`

**Expected Output**

```
+------------+-------------+---------+
| tstatus_id | trip_title  | trip_id |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|         33 | Jitesh Trip |      35 |
|         37 | Test_trip3  |      36 |
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

---

But I am not able to think how to solve this, i am getting output like this:

```
mysql> SELECT  tstatus_id,trip_history_status.trip_title,tripdetails.trip_id
    -> FROM (`trip_history_status`)
    -> JOIN `tripdetails` ON `tripdetails`.`trip_id` = `trip_history_status`.`trip_id`
    -> GROUP BY `tripdetails`.`trip_id`
    -> ORDER BY `tstatus_id` Asc;
+------------+-------------+---------+
| tstatus_id | trip_title  | trip_id |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|         33 | Jitesh Trip |      35 |
|         34 | Test_trip   |      36 |
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this in two stages.  First, determine the highest `tstatus_id` value for each distinct `trip_id`, as follows.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7884/1/0

```
         SELECT MAX(tstatus_id) AS tstatus_id, trip_id
           FROM trip_history_status
          GROUP BY trip_id
```

Then join that into your original table as follows   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7884/2/0

```
SELECT a.tstatus_id, a.trip_title, a.trip_id
  FROM trip_history_status AS a
  JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(tstatus_id) AS tstatus_id, trip_id
           FROM trip_history_status
          GROUP BY trip_id
       ) AS b ON a.tstatus_id = b.tstatus_id
```

The first query with `MAX() ... GROUP BY...` determines the latest ID for each trip. You then join it to the main table to retrieve the other information (the `trip_title`). The join operation serves to eliminate any rows without id values that are in the set of latest values for particular trips.

This query does the same thing in a slightly different way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7884/3/0

```
SELECT tstatus_id, trip_title, trip_id
  FROM trip_history_status
 WHERE tstatus_id IN (
         SELECT MAX(tstatus_id) AS tstatus_id
           FROM trip_history_status
          GROUP BY trip_id
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

SELECT * FROM trip_history_status ths, (SELECT trip_id,MAX(tstatus_id) AS tstatus_id FROM trip_history_status GROUP BY trip_id) tmp
WHERE tmp.tstatus_id=ths.tstatus_id

You can test it using this SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa834/3

Regards,